# SMTP response code 530 returned by Amazon SES

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, smtp, amazon-ses

I was trying to send an email through the Amazon SES SMTP interface **with php** referring this link :
[AWS SES SMTP interface with PHP](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-smtp-php.html#send-using-smtp-php-procedure)

It is giving an error of `authentication failure`. `[SMTP: Invalid response code received from server (code: 530, response: Must issue a STARTTLS command first)]`

Just to inform, I have moved out the the Amazon SES Sandbox, and I have my sender email verified.

How should I deal with this response code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me. Try adding the following to your enviornment variables:

`aws_access_key_id` as Variable Name and **your access id** as Variable Value

and,
`aws_secret_access_key` as Variable Name and **your access key** as Variable Value

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error. The problem was resolved by using the latest javax.mail jar file - https://github.com/javaee/javamail/releases/tag/JAVAMAIL-1_6_2

Comment: The question was regarding PHP, Javamail is likely not relevant to it. However, using latest libs if of course good and a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this from your home PC? Most internet providers block port 587, 25, etc.  I wonder if that's what happening.

Comment: @henry..I tried changing the port to 8080. It gave the following error: Email not sent. Failed to connect to email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:8080 [SMTP: Failed to connect socket: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (code: -1, response: )]